# Círculos CSS [diseño, animación]

Tags: html, css, diseño, angular7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]acudo por que no tengo mucha experiencia con css, 
ocupo hacer un diseño tipo los circulos de google plus. 
Que sea un circulo grande contenido por un grupo de círculos pequeños, 
y ocupo que tenga un circulo en medio como si fuera el centro de conjuntos. 
Algo como el numeral de los teléfonos antiguos de disco... 
Máximo 10 círculos al rededor de disco central..

De antemano muchas gracias. 
pd. 
Tengo que importar eso a un proyecto de Angular 7, si conocen alguna librería o algo que pueda ayudarme.

Se los agradeceré!

Comment: ¿Los círculos que ocupas tienen que ser estáticos, dinámicos o como sean?

Comment: Puedes agregar una imagen o un dibujo de lo que quieres conseguir?

Comment: Listo, disculpen por no agregar imagen!